# How to implement Header bidding using Prebid.js or advanced ads plugin in WordPress Website?

Tags: wordpress, prebid.js, header-bidding

I want to Implement Header Bidding on my WordPress website using an advanced ads plugin or provide any other solution for that.

I have installed an advanced ads plugin for that and also implemented it using Google ads but not able to get a proper solution for that.